# Where can I find the build # for a test result in the rally API?

Tags: rally

As the title suggests, how do I query the rally API to get a test results build #?
I have looked through the API and found a build object, but it only gives me a date. I know it exists as the views on rally1.rallydev.com show version #s.

My exact problem is: **I am looking to create a view that shows each test case along with the latest test result's build #**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see the `TestCaseResult` object? It has a string field called `Build` that represents the number of the build the test case was executed against to get the result.

Comment: I looked at that, but it was just giving me dates.